# perform two different actions in one db call with mongodb (3.4)

Tags: mongodb

I have an object that looks like:

```
{
    "personId": "134698",
    "name": "john",
    "age": 30,
    "contacts": 
    [
        {
            "name": "mark",
            "email": "mark@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "maria",
            "email": "maria@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "lastEdited": "2017-01-01"
}
```

and I want to update add new contact, so im doing:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "personId": "134698" },
    update: {"$push":{"contacts":{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","phoneNumber":"9384608374"}}}
})
```

problem is, I want to set "lastEdited" after pushed new contact, can I have it in the same call or I have to do another db call?

im working with mongo 3.4 and cant upgrade currently, and I know there is no transactions so if I need two calls for it its annoying cause I will need to protect myself here...

any recommendations here?

Comment: `update: {$push: {...}, $set: {....}}`

Comment: this is not working for me...```{"$push":{"contacts":{"name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","phoneNumber":"9384608374"}}, "$set": {"lastEdited": "2018-12-07"}}```

Comment: why not? any errors?

Comment: @AlexBlex it didnt work :/ im getting "null"

Comment: @AlexBlex ok now it did, it was syntax mistake

Comment: @AlexBlex now my issue is, if the addToSet succeed and the set didnt...? or vice versa, how should i go by with this ?

Comment: it is a single query, which is atomic on document level.

Comment: why you don't use update instead of findAndModify

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet cause findAndModify acquires a lock to the database so no other processes cam update it until this operation ends....from what I read :/

Comment: @AlexBlex that is great :)

Comment: @JohnBigs, could you share a link where you read about db lock? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/index.html#what-locks-are-taken-by-some-common-client-operations clearly states it locks individual documents. Same as update. The difference is only that findAndModify returns documents, and update returns result of the operation.

Comment: And also you can use findoneandupdate to get the updated document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add $set to update :

```
db.col1.findAndModify({
    query: { "personId": "134698" },
    update: {"$addToSet":{"contacts":{"name":"john2","email":"john@gmail.com","phoneNumber":"9384608374"}},"$set":{"lastEdited" : new Date()}}
})
```

Comment: now my issue is, if the addToSet succeed and the set didnt...? or vice versa, how should i go by with this ?

Comment: if part of update fails, so update fails, so nothing is saved